# Find all possible pairs of string - VBA

Tags: vba

In the column A, I have a list of strings. In the next column, I'd like to have all possible pairs (concatenated), such as:

|Column A | Column B|

|A|         |AB|

|B|         |AC|

|C|         |BC|

|...|       |...|

I have over 150 strings in my column A. I guess that I'll need a double loop, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Loop through every cell and then your interior loop will *also* loop through every cell, concatenating the results to column B.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

```
Option Explicit
' Modify if you want to delimit the concatenated values
Const delimiter As String = vbNullString
' If you want to concatenate a cell with itself, set this to True
Const compareSelf As Boolean = False

Sub pairs_mem()
'The pairs procedure calls on ConcatValues to write out data to sheet
' this procedures create pairwise combinations of each cell
' this does not omit duplicates (items nor pairs) or any other special considerations
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl1 As Range, cl2 As Range, dest As Range
Dim i As Long, length As Long

'Range of values to be concatenated, Modify as needed
Set rng = Range("A1:A7")
length = rng.Cells.Count
'Begin putting output in B1, Modify as needed
Set dest = Range("B1")
'Get the size of the output array
' output() is array container for the output values
If compareSelf Then
    ReDim output(1 To length * (length - 1))
Else
    ReDim output(1 To length ^ 2)
End If

i = 1
For Each cl1 In rng.Cells
    For Each cl2 In rng.Cells
        If cl1.Address = cl2.Address Then
            If compareSelf Then
                output(i) = ConcatValues(cl1, cl2)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Else
            output(i) = ConcatValues(cl1, cl2)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

dest.Resize(UBound(output)).Value = Application.Transpose(output)

End Sub
Function ConcatValues(ParamArray vals() As Variant)
    'Call this function to do the concatenation and returns the "i" value to caller
    Dim s$
    Dim itm
    For Each itm In vals
        s = s & itm & delimiter
    Next
    If delimiter <> vbNullString Then
        s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
    End If
    ConcatValues = s

End Function
```